# elasticsearch dsl translated from sql can't working

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, dsl

trying elasticsearch(6.4.2) sql rest api on yelp dataset,

```
read -r -d '' sql <<'EOF'
{
    "query":"select city, COUNT(*) AS c from \"yelp.business\" group by city"
}
EOF

curl -v -XPOST "http://$host/_xpack/sql?format=txt" -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d"$sql"
```

get right response

```
            city            |       c
----------------------------+---------------
Cleveland                   |2977
Cleveland Heights           |179
Cleveland Hghts.            |1
East Cleveland              |4
Mayfield Heights (Cleveland)|1
```

but tranlsate sql to dsl

```
query=`curl -v -XPOST "http://$host/_xpack/sql/translate?format=json" -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d"$sql"`
```

get following:

```
{
   "_source" : false,
   "size" : 0,
   "aggregations" : {
      "groupby" : {
         "composite" : {
            "sources" : [
               {
                  "2467" : {
                     "terms" : {
                        "order" : "asc",
                        "field" : "city.keyword",
                        "missing_bucket" : false
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "size" : 1000
         }
      }
   },
   "stored_fields" : "_none_"
}
```

execute translated dsl on search request

```
curl -XGET "http://$host/antkrill.event/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d"$query"
```

and get error

> failed to find field [city.keyword] and [missing_bucket] is not set

why search with sql is ok, but error with translated dsl

Answer (score 0):

my own problem！ the second query was executed with translated dsl on a different index！